# How do I let a user sign in from a different domain on Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

[This is slightly different than a previous question about having multiple domains share the same cookie.  It seemed like there wasn't an easy way to do that.]

I have a application at application.com.  A customer has app.customer.com pointed at my site on Heroku, and I have everything set up so that it renders a specific version of app correctly.  The issue is that I want a user at app.customer.com to be able to login.  I believe authlogic is now setting the cookie on application.com, so while it verifies the credentials, no session on customer.com is ever created.

Answer (score 0):

Since cookies cannot be shared across domains, you probably need to save an identifier in a database and also pass it through the url so when the client browser hits the new domain, it sends the token for the new domain session to see and match.

It should be a long cryptographically safe token, like a UUID to keep it from being guessed by attackers.

I'm not sure how the authlogic piece fits in though.