# One session across multiple domains authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authlogic

I have a ruby on rails app on heroku that receives traffic from 2 different request domains and displays 2 different sister sites based on the domain.
I am using authlogic to handle the user sessions, and I want it to be so that if a user is logged into one domain, they will also be automatically logged on to the other.
Of course sessions are not shared across domains so I was wondering what I need to do in order to make this work and configure this with authlogic.
I found this discussion:

[share session across multiple domains with the same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746351/share-session-across-multiple-domains-with-the-same-app)

which gives a general solution but that does not involve any Authlogic reference.
I also found this link:

[how do I let a user sign in from a different domain using authlogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058427/how-do-i-let-a-user-sign-in-from-a-different-domain-on-authlogic)

which also addresses the issue but the solution is very general and does not really address any authlogic configuration.

I am a relatively novel programmer so explicit advice/ recommended course of action would be very helpful.

Comment: Easiest solution is to share a subdomain. You might also get by with rack session injector. Next step is to implement a CAS service on one of the apps to have single sign on (SSO).

Comment: Thanks David, unfortunately sharing a subdomain is not an option. Also, your answer is a bit general I would say, not sure exactly what to do with the information you gave me besides to start googling the terms you mentioned which I know nothing about (rack session injector,  CAS service, single sign on)

Comment: Sorry about that. What you seek to do cannot be done without some advanced knowledge. If you control the links between the domains, then you can use this: https://github.com/incandescent/session-injector

Comment: Otherwise this is what solutions such as CAS (https://github.com/relevance/castronaut, http://rubycas.github.io/) make possible.

Comment: There is also an authlogic plugin for CAS: https://github.com/thurisaz/authlogic_cas. You can tell by the commit history that AuthLogic was hot as late as 2011 but gave way to Devise. You may have more joy with it.